# What is the `mkdir -p` equivalent in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, directory

In other words, in Powershell, how to create directories recursively, and not fail if each directory level already exist ?

Comment: `mkdir` in PowerShell is a wrapper for `New-Item -Type Directory` - and creating non-existing parent folders recursively is already the default behavior :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes, I just wanted to add this question in stackoverflow with an answer so that other people coming from Unix systems may find this question and gain some time looking for this :) (in case they forget about using the keyword 'recursive'). But thanks a lot for your help that would have helped me if I didn't know it anyway :)

Comment: See if [this](https://de.pinlivingcolor.com/890580-powershell-equivalent-of-linux-mkdir-RXARRH) can help you. Translate the site to English if you do not understand Deutsch.

Comment: @lbarqueira I've already posted an answer. This is a self-answered question to help other people.

Comment: @adamency Don't forget to accept your answer (whenever you can) :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Done :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `mkdir -p` command does two things:

- It creates directories (and files) recursively
- It doesn't print an error if any depth of the path already exists.

To achieve this behavior for in Powershell, use:

- `New-Item` which already creates paths recursively
- `-Force` to fail silently if paths already exist

Hence, to create `C:/x/y` where `x` and `y` must be **directories**, use:

`New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path C:/x/y -Force`

To create `C:/x/y` where `x` is a **directory** and `y` a **file**, use:

`New-Item -ItemType File -Path C:/x/y -Force`

Comment: Nice, though for full equivalence with `mkdir -p` you also need to suppress `New-Item`'s _output_: `$null = New-Item ...`. `New-Item -Type Directory` always returns a `[DirectoryInfo]` object (when  it succeeds), which either represents the newly created directory or, with `-Force`, if the directory already exists, the existing directory.